# Add store address details on footer and contact us page shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need to add store address details on footer and contact page

Is anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access store address detail using  **shop** shopify object.

Add below code on footer or contact page where you want to display address.

```
{{ shop.address }}
```